# GraphQL::Client::DynamicQueryError Expected definition to be assigned to a static constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, shopify-app

How to make proper **ShopifyAPI::GraphQL** method in Rails.

Trying the below code in `rails console` works fine.
But when I tried to put that code and make a method in Rails controller/model, i'm getting:

`GraphQL::Client::DynamicQueryError Expected definition to be assigned to a static constant`

```
shopify_client
client = ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.new

SHOP_NAME_QUERY = client.parse <<-'GRAPHQL'
 {
  shop {
   name
  }
 }
GRAPHQL

result = client.query(SHOP_NAME_QUERY)
```

I tried to play around with `variables`
following `https://github.com/github/graphql-client/blob/master/guides/dynamic-query-error.md` **but no success**.

How to make a method using the above function that will not return the mentioned error above.

**Sample Model method**:

```
def trial
  shopify_client
  client = ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.new
  shop_query = client.parse <<-'GRAPHQL'
    {
     shop {
      name
     }
    }
  GRAPHQL

  client.query(shop_query)
end
```

In **Gemfile**:  `gem 'shopify_api', git: 'https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api', branch: 'graphql-support'`

Comment: Can you share the exact code from the rails model?

Comment: @draganstankovic what do you mean? I just make a simple `def method` in model, given I have shopify_session and I'll make API request to Shopify

Comment: Sharing the exact code (from the model) that is throwing an error helps with narrowing down potential issues.

Comment: @draganstankovic I added the sample model method

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue a few days ago, I had to use `const_set` for setting the constant dynamically. So, using your example that would translate to

```
class Foo
  def trial
   #code to initialize shopify session here 
   set_query
   client.query(ProductQuery)
  end

  private 

  def set_query 
     query = <<-GRAPHQL
        {
          shop {
          name
        }
      }
    GRAPHQL
    Kernel.const_set(:ProductQuery, client.parse(query))
  end

  def client
    ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.new
  end
end
```

Shopify's GraphQL feature relies on the [Github GraphQL ruby client](https://github.com/github/graphql-client), which mandates query be defined in a constant. Also, the `shopify_api gem` mandates the existence of a Shopify session before you can use this method, depending on your setup you may not have a session defined if the constant is on the class body as that get executed first by the ruby interpreter. The way around this is to set the constant dynamically

Comment: if you put it in an "unless defined?(ProductQuery)" block you get rid of "warning: already initialized constant"

Comment: I tried this and works, but it causes memory leaks. I think because of setting a constant and running this query multiple times. I wonder if anyone knows how to prevent memory leaks with this?

Comment: This definitely works, but now I can't pass in variables to the query. Anyone have luck with the above method AND passing variables?

Answer (score 3):

**Finally got a simple one working**.

```
  Rails Model:

  SHOP_NAME_QUERY = ShopifyGraphQLClient.parse <<~GRAPHQL
  {
    shop {
      name
    }
  }
  GRAPHQL

  Rails Controller:

  def get_shop_name
    @shop.shopify_client (* very important)
    # shopify_client (client_id) is something like {"User-Agent"=>"xxx", "X-Shopify-Access-Token"=>"xxx"}
    # on my side it saved in DB,
    # Client ID: Any app that wants access to a shop’s data. A user must grant permission before the client can access any data.

    client = ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.new
    render json: client.query(Shop::SHOP_NAME_QUERY).data and return
  end


  Result like:
  {
    data: {
      shop: {
        name: "sample-shop-name"
      }
    },
    casted_data: { },
    errors: [ ]
  }

  References:
    https://github.com/mikeyhew/shopify_graphql_client
    https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api
    https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-with-oauth#scopes
```

I can now continue working with other requests...
Hope this help someone :)

Comment: When I use your solution I get "undefined local variable or method `shopify_client'". You write in another comment that ""shopify_client" is the session of Shopify" - but where is it defined - could you e.g. provide a code example that shows more of your controller?

Comment: `shopify_client ` is saved in DB, it came from Shop instance :)

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you use:

```
class MyModel
  ShopQuery = ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.new.parse <<-'GRAPHQL'
  {
    shop {
      name
      }
  }
  GRAPHQL

  # ....
  def trial
    shopify_client

    ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.new.query(ShopQuery)
  end

end
```

**Note:** `shop_query -> ShopQuery` because you need to use constant.

Comment: I tried, but getting => dynamic constant assignment (SyntaxError)
 ShopQuery = client.parse <<-'GRAPHQL'

Comment: I have edited the code a bit. Can you try the new version?

Comment: where is that error coming from (which line?). Also what does shopify_client do? You can perhaps preserve instance of a client similarly to what is done here: https://github.com/github/graphql-client

Comment: the error is from ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.new
I'm following & using https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/pull/431/files#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R224

"shopify_client" is the session of Shopify, it's needed before we can do an API request.

Comment: client = ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.new
TypeError: can't dup NilClass, because it needs to have {"User-Agent"=>"xxx", "X-Shopify-Access-Token"=>"xxx"} first before we can initialize GraphQL
which came from my Shop Model

Comment: thank you for trying to help me :) , I merged all ideas and come up with the solution.