# How is ShopifyAPI::GraphQL from the shopify_api gem supposed to be used? (undefined method `path=' )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to use the ShopifyAPI::GraphQL from the shopify_api gem, which seemed to work fine in my local environment, but I am having problems in my Heroku environment.

The first error seemed to be related to a bug in the shopify_api gem and was fixed by setting the api version i.e. ShopifyAPI::Base.api_version = "2019-10" (even though it was already set in the config/initializers/shopify_app.rb with config.api_version = "2019-10").

Moving on I get the following error when starting the server in the Heroku environment:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `path=' for nil:NilClass
info   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/shopify_api-8.1.0/lib/shopify_api/resources/graphql.rb:10:in `initialize'
```

Looking at the lines in the graphql.rb file from shopify_api that fails:

```
uri = Base.site.dup #line 9
uri.path = Base.api_version.construct_graphql_path #line 10
```

it seems to be caused by the fact that Base.site is nil, which makes sense as there is no session at the time the server is started.

As far as I can see, the graphql queries need to be constants, and as they refer the graphql client, I instantiate the graphql client as a class parameter:

```
@@client = ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.new
```

The above line seem to be initialized during server start (I am very new to rails), and as mentioned the error occurs because there is no session and hence no site at the time.

So I must be using the graphql component wrong. My question is, how am I supposed to use the class ShopifyAPI::GraphQL? Where should I e.g. place the ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.new code?

Or to make the question more general - the graphql-client requires the queries and thus the graphql client ShopifyAPI::GraphQL to be defined as constants. How do I prevent the constants from being initialized during server startup, as the there is no session at server startup which is required when initializing the graphql client?

Thanks,
-Louise

Comment: It is possible to successfully query the graphql API by using the const_set solution mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382830/graphqlclientdynamicqueryerror-expected-definition-to-be-assigned-to-a-stati although it is also mentioned that this gives memory leak problems. I will not close this issue for now, as I hope to find a solution that does not give memory leak problems. An alternative is to use another gem for graphql queries, as there's also a general memory issue in the shopify_api gem - see https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/issues/511