# Dynamic constant assignment when using Graphql for Shopify API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, shopify

I am using Graphql on the Shopify API and also needing to use variables in my query. [I found this post, but it didn't work because I am using those query variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382830/graphqlclientdynamicqueryerror-expected-definition-to-be-assigned-to-a-stati)

This is the exact error I'm getting:

```
SyntaxError (/home/fc-gui/app/controllers/concerns/product_graphql.rb:26: dynamic constant assignment
FIRST_PRODUCTS = CLIENT.parse <<-'GRAPHQL'
```

And then here is the method where I'm trying to run my query

```
  def run_first_query
    FIRST_PRODUCTS = CLIENT.parse <<-'GRAPHQL'
    query($first: Int){
      products(first: $first) {
        pageInfo {
          hasNextPage
        }
        edges {
          cursor
          node {
            id
            title
            featuredImage {
              originalSrc
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    GRAPHQL
    first = { "first": number_of_products_to_return}
    @query_result = CLIENT.query(FIRST_PRODUCTS, variables: first)
    get_last_cursor
  end
```

I've tried creating the client similar to the aforementioned post, like these two options, but no luck:

```
CLIENT = ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.new
##
def graphql_client
  ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.new
end
```

Anyone able to run graphql queries with variables, in Ruby and NOT get this error?

Comment: Isn't the problem that you're trying to write to the constant FIRST_PRODUCTS inside a method body? Can you try using a method variable instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And here is the solution. Super hard to believe this is a "new" way of accessing data via an API. Its slower, more complicated and much more verbose. I don't get the benefit at all.

```
  def run_first_query
    query = <<-'GRAPHQL'
    query($first: Int){
      products(first: $first) {
        pageInfo {
          hasNextPage
        }
        edges {
          cursor
          node {
            id
            title
            featuredImage {
              originalSrc
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    GRAPHQL
    first = { 
      "first": number_of_products_to_return,
    }
    Kernel.const_set(:ProductQuery, graphql_client.parse(query))
    @query_result = graphql_client.query(ProductQuery, variables: first)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using constants using this style:

```
query = ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.client.parse <<-'GRAPHQL'
  {
    shop {
      name
    }
  }
GRAPHQL

result = ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.client.query(query)
puts "Shop name: #{result.data.shop.name}"
```

I didn't set up your exact query but this solved the problem for the queries I was making.

Reference from their docs: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/blob/master/docs/graphql.md